# Position index from MotionEvent in EditText

Tags: android

Given an `EditText` and its `OnTouch` event, I overridden it, and returned true. This prevents the soft keys from showing up. But it also prevents inner calculation of the position index inside the `EditText`. That is `myEditText.getSelectionStart()` will return always 0.

Is there a way to calculate (or an Android function that can calculate) the position index based on the `MotionEvent` argument of the `OnTouch` event?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please describe more broadly what you are trying to achieve? I have a soft keyboard device, so I can't swear, but I doubt a hard keyboard device would pop a soft one - therefore I suppose you are trying to prevent a soft keyboard device to pop it... but what use is an EditText if the user can't type in it? Maybe another widget could be more useful? Hence why it would be nice for you to give a broader view of your idea. Best regards.

Comment: Hi, @pouzzler, I indeed want to prevent the soft kesy from showing up, and, instead, show my own keys, which are very few, and consiste of certain chars (about 12 specific keys). I can immitate soft keys without problems, except for touch-set-cursor position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching SO and googling I understand the solution isn't clear.
So I solved it by compromising.

I supply right/left arrows on my keyboard with which the user can move the cursor.
If the user taps the edit text while my keyboard is shown, he will get a Toast telling him to use the keyboard for what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution in Android's APIs today called getOffsetForPosition(float x,float y) since API level 14, to obtain the character position where the touch was made on the edittext. It's basically a method you can invoke from inside one of your listeners for the edittext (onClick or onTouch) as follows:

```
int click_position = <your_edittext>.getOffsetForPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

where event is the MotionEvent passed into the listener.
This gives the position of the character on the edittext view at which a touch was made, using which one can position the cursor using

```
edittext.setSelection(click_position);
```

But, if you want this to work on a device that uses Android versions earlier than 4.0 (ICS) (API level 13 or less), this API is not available.  However, you can develop your own method for API versions below 14, using other APIs that are available (which is essentially what Google did from API level 14).
i did that and was able to successfully get the position index on the edittext from the motionevent. i basically compiled a static method with the same name, from other API calls available in Android from API level 1.   i am not sure if there is a need to post the code for older API levels now.  If there is interest, i will post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a year old, but I'm currently trying to do the same thing. My reasoning is that I need a good solution for handling localized numberDecimal EditText input, which Android doesn't do well natively: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626 and all the threads on SO trying to deal with that issue don't work when manufacturers like Samsung fail to take the "digits" parameter.

This isn't final code for translating the onTouch event in a field into a cursor position, but I just started about half an hour ago so here's where I'm at in my R&D for doing that.

It works marginally. I just need to figure out how to calculate the divisor parameter for different screens. A value of 16 works well for my tiny old phone, but not for a 7 inch tablet with a higher density.

[EDIT: works well on the devices I've tested it on. Too early to tell if this holds true for more devices.]

```
myField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                try {
                    float dp = App.get().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int div = (int) (10 * dp);
                    int x = (int) me.getX();
                    int pos = (v.getWidth() - x) / div;
                    int strlen = ((EditText)v).getText().toString().length();
                    int curpos = strlen - pos;

                    v.requestFocus();

                    if (curpos < 0) {
                        ((EditText)v).setSelection(0);
                    } else {
                        ((EditText)v).setSelection(curpos);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(App.TAG, "onTouch exception " + e.toString());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use `(int)((EditText)v).getPaint().measureText("0")` to determine symbol lenght,  if View is EditText